# Accessing This Array In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm playing around in the console.

```
  2.0.0-p451 :060 > u = User.find(1)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Patrick Sullivan", email: "xxxx@gmail.com", created_at: "2014-03-10 20:35:43", updated_at: "2014-03-25 00:48:45", password_digest: "$2a$10$ZXeEjtJAoMpdOpe.3H7avOdO9XMCuAjwAkIm10DWtZ3I...", remember_token: "61ed84e1184181365e0591e6a309e575f6072b69", admin: true, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, city_id: nil, hood_id: nil, burrough_id: nil> 
2.0.0-p451 :061 > u.pending_invited_by
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friendable_id" WHERE "friendships"."friend_id" = ? AND (("friendships"."pending" = 't' AND "friendships"."blocker_id" IS NULL))  [["friend_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 102, name: "Patrick Sullivan", email: "deedee@gmail.com", created_at: "2014-03-11 00:12:19", updated_at: "2014-03-25 00:48:20", password_digest: "$2a$10$y6T3PpMQkMOmXiO6c/5xE.HZ4GYPcUvy907IpyPaHpuK...", remember_token: "7c8d16661fa92747516970fbf3aafae6151c2848", admin: false, image_file_name: "aboutuspeendee.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 219210, image_updated_at: "2014-03-14 15:32:47", city_id: "Brooklyn", hood_id: nil, burrough_id: nil>]>
```

What would I have to append to u.pending_invited_by to have the name of user 102 to be returned (and I'm aware they are both Patrick Sullivan).

This should be an easy upvote and green for someone.  I've been playing in console for 15 minutes.  I'm new to ruby and rails!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Bam.  That did it.  Sevens, if you'd like to post that I'd give you an upvote and green.  I'll have to google some stuff.  ie what .map does =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to return the result of calling a method on each member of the ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy (it's not an array, but it acts like one).

Because you want to call `name` on each member of the collection, you can call

```
.map { |u| u.name }
```

or simply shorten that to

```
.map(&:name)
```

Comment: If I wanted to loop through the images too, could I do {|u| u.name, u.image}

Comment: what are you actually doing this for? If it's for output in a view, you can simply iterate over the collection with `each`, and then print out whatever you like for each user.

Comment: This worked.  <%= current_user.pending_invited_by.map do  |u|  %>
    <%= image_tag u.image.url(:thumb) %>
    <%= u.name. %>
    <% end %>

Comment: anyway to get rid of that ["\n"]

Comment: You're using `map`, which will return the result of the block, and then you're printing it out. You don't need the = in the `<%= current_user` part. You also don't need `map` here - a simple `each` will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the raw values and not instances of `User`, use [#pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
u.pending_invited_by.pluck(:name) # ['Patrick Sullivan']

u.pending_invited_by.pluck(:name).first # 'Patrick Sullivan'
```